# Does append() need to be on the body tag to add to dom tree?

Tags: jquery, dom

I just need this to be cleared up, if I use append(), does it need to be on $("body") in order to add an element to the dom tree for access or can it be on any element?
Just to clarify, I know you can do append on any element but I want to make sure what I need to append to for it to be in the DOM for later access, thank you for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be called on any element.

Comment: You could have tried & answered this yourself in the time it took to ask the question... http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: I did try it on any element but it didn't work, then after asking, I discovered that it was because the element was hidden so the width didn't work that's why i was unable to grab it